# How do you reference multiple html pages with one css sheet?

Tags: html, css, reference, background, targeting

Here's my code.
In the screenshot provided I included two situations in which me trying to reference the css style sheet does not work.

In the html, I used < body class="1" >. And then in the stylesheet I referenced it by saying body.1{}. This does not work. I tried making the background black and that won't show. Previously, I tried name it "home" instead of "1", that didn't work either. It also wouldn't let me set a background image in the css file so I had to add an image in the html instead.

The same things go for < body class="2" > and body.2{}.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response. Here is how I have the link formatted in the head. <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="midterm.css"> Is this correct? Or is there an error in how i'm linking it?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use numbers as class names.

"A valid name should start with an underscore (_), a hyphen (-) or a letter (a-z) which is followed by any numbers, hyphens, underscores, letters. A name should be at least two characters long. Cannot start with a digit, two hyphens or a hyphen followed by a number."

https://pineco.de/css-quick-tip-the-valid-characters-in-a-custom-css-selector/

Try something like:

```
a1
```

Code pen for demonstration: 
https://codepen.io/jamiecalder/pen/rNNVgMj

Comment: Thank you for the response, I'm going to implement this further and call it something like index. Changing the class name didn't work so I think i need to change "body".